# How to access variable assigned inside API?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I'm trying to run the API function, change the variables, and then show those results in the view.

I looked at other solutions on Stack Overflow, but didn't understand any of them.

Therefore, I wrote some dummy code just to show what I mean. It **looks** simple but it's been super frustrating and complex.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var weather: UILabel!

    var temperature = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getWeatherData()

        weather.text = temperature // This still returns an empty string

    }

    func getWeatherData() {
        Alamofire.request("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather", method: .get).responseJSON {
            response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {

                print("Success! Got the weather data")

                let weatherJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                temperature = String(weatherJSON["main"]["temp"].double)

            } else {
                print("Error \(String(response.result.error))")
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

How do I make the new value for `temperature` accessible globally?

Comment: `temperature` is getting set from `getWeatherData()`; only later than you're expecting. Since the Alamofire request is asynchronous `getWeatherData()` will return immediately and `weather.text` will then be set to the still empty string. For this simple example, set `weather.text = temperature` after setting `temperature = String...` and it'll get updated.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

Comment: @Don Ah sorry I probably didn’t explain well... I was wondering how to access the newly assigned value outside of the API call? Setting it inside would work but then I can’t access it anywhere else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Don mentioned `getWeatherData()` is asynchronous function and result of API call will be available after function call finished. You can solve it as:

```swift
var temperature = "" {
    didSet { weather.text = temperature }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getWeatherData()
}

...
self.temperature = String(weatherJSON["main"]["temp"].double)
...
```

Comment: Thanks! And is there a way for me to change the value of `temperature` itself? Like what if I want to use `temperature` in other parts of my code? 
Something like ```var temperature = "" {
    didSet { temperature = temperature }
}```

Comment: @RichardReis sorry, I don't understand question, could you be more specific?

Comment: So in your answer, I'm changing `weather.text` to the new `temperature` value. But what if I want to use the new `temperature` value in other parts of my code? Is there a way to just give `temperature` a new value after `didSet`? Instead of assigning it to `weather.text`?

Comment: In `didSet` block you can do with `temperature` whatever you want: change it, pass it as argument to function, call other functions, etc

Comment: But if I do ```var temperature = "" { didSet { temperature = temperature } }``` I get a `Assigning a property to itself` warning

Comment: @RichardReis yes, you assigning `temperature` to `temperature`, that valid code, but doesn't make sense, so you getting warning about it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190540/discussion-between-richard-reis-and-manwithbear).

Answer (score 2):

Change your temperature variable to look like this. As @Don mentioned in their comment your web request is running asynchronously and returning after `viewDidLoad` is called.

```
var temperature = "" {
    didSet {
        weather.text = temperature
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I asked this before but I'll ask it here too, is there a way for me to change the value of `temperature` itself? Like what if I want to use `temperature` in other parts of my code? Something like ```var temperature = "" { didSet { temperature = temperature } }```

Comment: Not a problem, you can use temperature throughout other areas without a problem. The reason your code wasn't working initially was because `viewDidLoad` was executing and completed before `getWeatherData` was finished. If you add a few `print` statements around your code I think that will help you see the order a little more clearly.

Comment: It still doesn't work if I want to assign `temperature` somewhere else. For example, if I did a UIScrollView and wanted to put the new `temperature` value in same of the slides (without putting the entire UIScrollView function inside of the temperature `didSet`). How could I access the new `temperature` value outside of `didSet`?

Comment: It will work outside of `didSet` you just need to make sure to call it after your response has returned. I would suggest creating a function named `updateUI` or similar at the same level as `getWeatherData` and call it from inside the `getWeatherData` function. As long as `temperature` has been set before it you'll be able to access the data.